# Gparted doesn't create partition table

Tags: gparted, format

I wrongly used to command `dd` to create a bootable usb specifying the partition of the USB, and not the disk (with `of=/dev/sdb1` instead of `of=/dev/sdb` and now I'm trying to recover the USB.

When I open it at Gparted it shows me a 64 MB disk with a warning that there's no partition table and "unrecognizable disk label". According to what I read I have to create a partition using Device> Create Partition Table, which is what I try, but no tables are created. When I click I get no error and Gparted loads something, but the result is the same as before: no partition table.

Any ideas?

I also already tried

```
 $ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=512 count=2048
2048+0 records in
2048+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1,0 MB) copied, 0,266834 s, 3,9 MB/s
```

But nothing changed. What Am I missing?

Comment: Did you have an sdb1 for dd to write to? Or where did it send data? Did you just try writing image again? The dd writing does not create a standard partitioned flash drive since ISO is a hybrid DVD/flash drive image. I do try to avoid using dd as any typo causes major issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by re-writing the `.iso` file in the USB correctly using `dd` (as @oldfred suggested) and then formating it twice again with gparted.